# Chainlink Node -Job Run: requestData: while unmarshalling JSON: invalid character '$' looking for beginning of value - bad input for task

Tags: chainlink, toml

It appears that the fetch task is not working. I haven't found any bugs, and compared this task to a job that worked.

Fetch task that succeeded ->

```
fetch [type=bridge name="armanino-trust-token" requestData=
"{\"id\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \"data\": { \"tokenName\": $(decode_cbor.tokenName)}}"]
```

Fetch task that is failing ->

```
fetch [type=bridge name="rasp-pi-cpu" requestData=
"{\"id\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \"data\": { \"pi-temp\": $(decode_cbor.pi-temp)}}"]
```

This is the error that appears in my logs ->

```
requestData: while unmarshalling JSON: invalid character '$' looking for beginning of value; js: {"id": { "__chainlink_key_path__": "jobSpec.externalJobID" }, "data": { "pi-temp": $(decode_cbor.pi-temp)}}: bad input for task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashes are not allowed in pipeline variable names.  Replace `pi-temp` with `pi_temp` and it should work.